# Caputure expression with original format

Tags: r, expression

I try capture an expressions but `deparse()` function cutoff input. Is there any way to keep original source format (line breaks)?

```
f <- function(expr) {
    cat(deparse(substitute(expr)), sep = "\n")
}
f(mean(1))
#> mean(1)
f({
    head(mtcars)
    mean(rnotm(100))
})
#> {
#>     head(mtcars)
#>     mean(rnotm(100))
#> }
f(function(x, y) {
    x + y
})
#> function(x, y) {
#>     x + y
#> }
f(LDF <- list(
    data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
    data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE))
))
#> LDF <- list(data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 
#>     1000, replace = TRUE)), data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 
#>     1000, replace = TRUE)))
f({
    LDF <- list(
        data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
        data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE))
    )
})
#> {
#>     LDF <- list(data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = sample(LETTERS, 
#>         1000, replace = TRUE)), data.frame(V1 = runif(1000), 
#>         V2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)))
#> }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "expected source format" ?

Comment: I think he wants to keep the line breaks.

Comment: Have you tried `I()`? I hear it's supposed to take whatever you put in it literally.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: can you post answer with a code example?

Comment: Have you looked at the optional arguments for `deparse` in `?deparse`.

Comment: @NGaffney: sure. The relevant argument of the `deparse` is `width.cutoff`. But it does not allow to achieve the desired effect. As well as `deparseOpts`. `useSource` works only with a function definitions.